# How to fix dates in the generated csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I`m writing a program that you put the log and it generates a csv about the exchange of virtual desktops, but I`m having a big problem cause when it generates csv it gets all virtual desktop 1, then all 2,3,4,5, and 6.

I wanted it to be by the day, how do I do that?

My code is like this right now, how do I get the events in a day and not separated by number?

```
filepath = 'dgnet.log'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    cnt = 1
    Fls = []
    while line:
        if "Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop" in line.strip():
            loc = []
            loc.append(line.strip().split("> ---")[0])
            loc.append(line.strip().split("> ---")[1])
            Fls.append(loc)
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
df = pd.DataFrame(Fls, columns=['Time', 'Name'])
gk = df.groupby('Name')
finallist = []
for name, group in gk:
    g = group
    g['Time2'] = g['Time'].shift(1)
    for i in range(len(g)):
        loc1 = []
        if i % 2 == 0:
            x = np.nan
        else:
            x = g.iloc[i, 2]
        loc1.append(x)
        loc1.append(g.iloc[i, 0])
        loc1.append(g.iloc[i, 1])
        finallist.append(loc1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(finallist, columns=['StartTime', 'EndTime', 'Name'])
df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df2 = df1[df1['StartTime'] != 0]
df2['date'] = ""

d1 = 1
d = datetime.datetime.now()
l = len(df2)
Lxs = []
for i in range(len(df2)):
    if i == 0:
        df2.iloc[i, 3] = (datetime.datetime.now()).date()
    if i != 0:
        s = pd.to_datetime(df2.iloc[i, 0]).time()
        e = pd.to_datetime(df2.iloc[i, 1]).time()
        pe = pd.to_datetime(df2.iloc[i - 1, 1]).time()
        if e > s:
            df2.iloc[i, 3] = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=d1)).date()
        if pe > s:
            d1 = d1 + 1
            df2.iloc[i, 3] = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=d1)).date()
        #             print(i,datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=d1))
        elif e < s:
            df2.iloc[i, 3] = np.NaN
            Lxs.append([df2.iloc[i, 0], "23:59:00", df2.iloc[i, 2],
                        (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=d1)).date()])
            d1 = d1 + 1
            Lxs.append(["00:00:01", df2.iloc[i, 1], df2.iloc[i, 2],
                        (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=d1)).date()])
            l = l + 1

Lxsdf = pd.DataFrame(Lxs, columns=['StartTime', 'EndTime', 'Name', 'date'])
x = df2.append(Lxsdf)
x.fillna(0, inplace=True)
x1 = x[x['date'] != 0]
x1.index = x1['date']
x1.sort_index(inplace=True)
x1['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(x1['EndTime'])
x1['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(x1['StartTime'])
x1['s1'] = x1['EndTime'] - x1['StartTime']
x1.to_csv('file3.csv')
```

I expect to be like:

```
taskbarbuttons auf desktop 1 = 50 seconds
taskbarbuttons auf desktop 2 = 1 minutes
```

and currently it's:

```
09:42:58    23:07:00     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
12:59:04    13:42:08     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
03:59:13    04:44:39     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
13:24:59    13:25:26     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
19:24:15    13:03:02     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
13:12:29    13:33:43     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
13:35:43    07:45:14     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
07:53:27    10:51:30     Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1
```

and then all 2,3,4,5, and 6.

Comment: I've read this question twice over and I still have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: instead of `line = p.readline()` (two times) and `while line` - so you have 3 lines of code - you can use single line of code: `for line in p:`. It is very popular method to read lines from file.

Comment: `split("> ---")` gives you list so you don't have to use `loc.append(...)` but directly `loc = line.strip().split("> ---")`

Comment: You should add example data from previous question to better understand problem. You could also add link to previous question - some people may not know it.

Comment: I don't understand some of you calculations. You should use names of variables which means something - ie. `start_time` instead of `s`, `end_time` instead of `e`.

Comment: probably most of calculation could be done without `for i in range(len(df2))` but using one line like `df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime']).time()`

Comment: @furas but like the output that I want is  "day 1 desktop 1 was used for " hours that it was used
"day 1 desktop 2 was used for"  hours that it was used
"day 1 desktop 3 was used for " hours that it was used
"day 1 desktop 4 was used for"  hours that it was used
 and I`m getting this output on the csv  
how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: I’ll second everything @furas has said so far, and admire their patience. Could you include some example data? I can take a look at the program once I can actually run it.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile there is [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600888/compare-multiple-lines-in-a-text-file-using-python) with some data which I uses also to create solution for this question.

Comment: Since your timestamps are in the "hh:mm:ss" format, how can you know how much time has elapsed? For example, how much time has elapsed between 03:05:00 and 04:06:00? 1 hour and 1 minute? 1000 days, 1 hour, and 1 minute? If at all possible you should take a step back and make changes to whatever is producing those logs, before trying to mess with the data.

Comment: (And if you do have a way to determine elapsed time, why isn't it included in your post?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most elements I made without `iterrows()`. I needed it only to split row into two rows when time passes midnight.

For test I used `io.StringIO()` to simulate file with data.

I tried to add comments to describe code
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

```
# read full file
#text = open(filename).read()

text = '''09:43:04> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 2

12:37:20> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 6

23:07:00> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1

23:07:07> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 2

23:07:09> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 3

12:59:04> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1

13:41:53> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 5

13:47:09> --- Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 3'''


# --- read file ---

#filepath = 'dgnet.log'
#with open(filepath) as fp:

import io
with io.StringIO(text) as fp: # simulate file with data
    data = []
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if "Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop" in line:
            row = line.strip().split("> ---")
            data.append(row)

# --- calculations ---

# create DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['StartTime', 'Name'])

# convert string to datetime. I don't convert to time

df['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'])

# create second column to calculate difference 

df['EndTime'] = df['StartTime'].shift(-1)

# fill last cell with current datetime (without microsecond)

iloc_endtime = df.columns.get_loc('EndTime')
df.iloc[-1, iloc_endtime] = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

print('--- df at start ---')
# I use columns names because sometimes I get columns in different order
print(df[['Name', 'StartTime', 'EndTime']])

# iterate rows to split at midnight and add day number I also add day to `StartTime` and a `EndTime` 

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
day = 1

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(row)

    if row['EndTime'] < row['StartTime']:
        # split into two rows on midnight
        row2 = row.copy()

        # first row ends at midnight-1second
        row['EndTime']    = row['EndTime'].replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)

        # second row starts at midnight
        row2['StartTime'] = row['StartTime'].replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

        # add day to first row
        dt = pd.Timedelta(day,'D')
        row['StartTime'] += dt
        row['EndTime']   += dt
        row['Day'] = day
        new_df = new_df.append(row)

        # add day+1 to second row
        day += 1

        dt = pd.Timedelta(day,'D')
        row2['StartTime'] += dt
        row2['EndTime']   += dt
        row2['Day'] = day
        new_df = new_df.append(row2)
    else:
        # add only day
        dt = pd.Timedelta(day,'D')
        row['StartTime'] += dt
        row['EndTime']   += dt
        row['Day'] = day
        new_df = new_df.append(row)

df = new_df 

print('--- splited rows and added days ---')        
print(df[['Name', 'StartTime', 'EndTime', 'Day']])

# calculate END - START

df['DiffTime'] = df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime']

print('--- diff time ---')
print(df[['Name', 'StartTime', 'EndTime', 'Day', 'DiffTime']])

# group by `Name` or `Name` and `Day` to sum DiffTimes

#total_time = df.groupby(['Name'])['DiffTime'].sum()  #.dt.seconds
total_time = df.groupby(['Name', 'Day'])['DiffTime'].sum()  #.dt.seconds

print('--- total time ---')
print(total_time)

# reset index to convert index to column 
final_df = total_time.reset_index()

print('--- final df ---')
print(final_df)
```

Final DataFrame looks like

```
                            Name  Day DiffTime
0   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1  1.0 00:00:07
1   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1  2.0 00:42:49
2   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 2  1.0 02:54:18
3   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 3  1.0 00:52:50
4   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 3  2.0 22:13:29
5   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 5  2.0 00:05:16
6   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 6  1.0 10:29:40
```

It can be sorted by Day and Name

```
final_df = final_df.sort_values(['Day', 'Name']) )
```

to get DataFrame

```
                            Name  Day DiffTime
0   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1  1.0 00:00:07
2   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 2  1.0 02:54:18
3   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 3  1.0 00:52:50
6   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 6  1.0 10:29:40
1   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 1  2.0 00:42:49
4   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 3  2.0 22:23:32
5   Taskbarbuttons auf Desktop 5  2.0 00:05:16
```

which can be used to display expected result.

For example

```
for index, row in final_df.iterrows():
    day = int(row['Day'])
    number = row['Name'].split(' ')[-1]
    time = str(row['DiffTime']).split(' ')[-1]
    print('day {} desktop {} was used for {}'.format(day, number, time))
```

gives

```
day 1 desktop 1 was used for 00:00:07
day 1 desktop 2 was used for 02:54:18
day 1 desktop 3 was used for 00:52:50
day 1 desktop 6 was used for 10:29:40
day 2 desktop 1 was used for 00:42:49
day 2 desktop 3 was used for 22:38:24
day 2 desktop 5 was used for 00:05:16
```

Comment: Using `iterrows` is probably a terrible idea! The [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) state that `iterrows` "does *not* preserve dtypes across the rows", is slower than `itertuples`, and that "You should *never modify* something you are iterating over." Be careful!

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I know that pandas has methods to make things without loop and for the most modifications I reduced loop from original code. The only thing which I don't know how to do without loop is to use one row to create two new rows and increase `day` at the same time - which I need to count days because original DataFrame has times without dates. SO I used iterrows and create new dataframe. Maybe you have idea how to get rid of this one loop.

Comment: I will take a look at getting rid of the loop, but what I meant is that if you are using explicit iteration then using `itertuples` is far better! I will make the change, and run some benchmarks for the sake of curiosity.